# Flask get public IP from client behind NGINX - not quite working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx, flask

I'm struggling to get the public IP from clients.

I have a Flask app served using Waitress behind an NGINX running on an AWS EC2 instance.

When I access the website using https://myservice.com, I get the AWS EC2 private IPv4.

When I access the website using https://www.myservive.com, it works: I get the public IP from my machine as intended. It also works if I access https://myservice.com but using a VPN. Finally, it also works if I access https://1.2.3.4 (where 1.2.3.4 is the public IPv4 assigned to my AWS EC2 instance.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

Here are the relevant configurations:

NGINX:

```
upstream flask {
    server flask:5000;
}

server {
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name myservice.com www.myservice.com;
    return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myservice.com www.myservice.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myservice.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myservice.com/privkey.pem; 
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    client_max_body_size 5M;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://flask;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
        autoindex off;
    }
}
```

Flask:

```py
# __init__.py
def create_app():
    ...
    app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(
        app.wsgi_app, x_for=1, x_proto=1, x_host=1, x_prefix=1
    )
    ...
    @app.route('/inspect_public_ip')
    def inspect_public_ip():
        obj = {
            'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': request.environ.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'),
            'HTTP_X_REAL_IP': request.environ.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP'),
            'REMOTE_ADDR': request.environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR'),
            'list': request.headers.getlist("X-Forwarded-For"),
            'X-Forwarded-For': request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-For', None),
            'X-Real-IP': request.headers.get('X-Real-IP', None),
            'access_route_all': request.access_route,
        }
        return jsonify(obj)
    ...
    return app
```

Docker:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  flask:
    command: [ "waitress-serve", "--port", "5000", "--call", "myservice:create_app" ]
    expose:
      - 5000
    ...
    
  nginx:
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - flask
    ...
```

PS: I believe I already read all StackOverflow's questions regarding this topic (there are a lot) and tried to solve the problem using them (as it can be shown in the code above), but none of the solutions worked so far (which are basically to set `proxy_set_header`s on NGINX and `ProxyFix` in Flask.

Comment: Update: if I remove the AAAA record (IPv6) from the DNS records, it works. I don't know why this happens, though...